# RC4 Encryption and decryption in UTF-8 ASP classic

Tags: encryption, utf-8, asp-classic, rc4-cipher

Is there a way to make this work in an ASP page?
It was working fine with charset windows-1253 but now I have to convert my site
to UTF-8 and the only problem I have is encryption and decryption. I have encrypted members registration passwords and now with UTF-8, after decryption passwords looks like this: `2��8��6`

Please I nead some help (sorry for my English).
This is RC4 code:

```
Dim sbox(255)
   Dim rc4Key(255)

   Sub RC4Initialize(strPwd)

      dim tempSwap, a, b      

      intLength = len(strPwd)

      for a = 0 To 255

         rc4Key(a)  = asc(mid(strpwd, (a mod intLength)+1, 1))

         sbox(a) = a                       
      next

      b = 0

      for a = 0 To 255
         b = (b + sbox(a) + rc4Key(a)) Mod 256         
         tempSwap = sbox(a)
         sbox(a) = sbox(b)
         sbox(b) = tempSwap
      Next

   End Sub

   function EnDeCrypt(plaintxt, psw)      

      dim temp, a, i, j, k, cipherby, cipher      

      i = 0
      j = 0

      RC4Initialize psw

      for a = 1 To Len(plaintxt)
         i  = (i + 1) Mod 256
         j  = (j + sbox(i)) Mod 256
         temp   = sbox(i)
         sbox(i)= sbox(j)
         sbox(j)= temp

         k  = sbox((sbox(i) + sbox(j)) Mod 256)

         cipherby   = Asc(Mid(plaintxt, a, 1)) Xor k
         cipher     = cipher & Chr(cipherby)         
      next

      enDeCrypt = cipher            

   end function

   function RC4EnCryptASC(plaintxt, psw)      

      dim temp, a, i, j, k, cipherby, cipher      

      i = 0
      j = 0

      RC4Initialize psw

      for a = 1 To Len(plaintxt)
         i  = (i + 1) Mod 256
         j  = (j + sbox(i)) Mod 256
         temp   = sbox(i)
         sbox(i)= sbox(j)
         sbox(j)= temp

         k      = sbox((sbox(i) + sbox(j)) Mod 256)

         cipherby   = Asc(Mid(plaintxt, a, 1)) Xor k         
         cipher     = cipher & "|"& cipherby         
      next            

      RC4EnCryptASC = cipher            

   end function

   function RC4DeCryptASC(plaintxt, psw)      

      plaintxt = transformToCHR(plaintxt)

      dim temp, a, i, j, k, cipherby, cipher      

      i = 0
      j = 0      

      dim arrayEncrypted            

      RC4Initialize psw         

       for a = 1 To Len(plaintxt)
         i  = (i + 1) Mod 256
         j  = (j + sbox(i)) Mod 256
         temp   = sbox(i)
         sbox(i)= sbox(j)
         sbox(j)= temp

         k  = sbox((sbox(i) + sbox(j)) Mod 256)

         cipherby   = Asc(Mid(plaintxt, a, 1)) Xor k
         cipher     = cipher & Chr(cipherby)         
      next

      RC4DeCryptASC = cipher                       

   end function

function transformToCHR(plaintxt)


      dim returnText, arrayEncrypted
      arrayEncrypted = split(plaintxt, "|")            

      returnText=""            

      for a = 1 to ubound(arrayEncrypted)         
         returnText=returnText&CHR(arrayEncrypted(a))         
      next            

      transformToCHR = returnText
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to use AscW function and the equivalent other functions to deal with Unicode characters?

Comment: OK, but the Unicode code point will be different from the value of the Windows-1253 (extended ISO-8859-1 Latin) point.

Comment: I will decrypt passwords with this script and Windows-1253 and store then in database without encryption. Then I will turn then site to UTF-8 and I will encrypt then using this script edited by AscW function. But how do I have to add AscW function in the script ???

Comment: @WebStyler ascw and so on are built in vbscript functions

Comment: More help would be nice.
Where do I have to put AscW () in the above script ?

I call functions RC4EnCryptASC and RC4DeCryptASC.

Comment: man is that your script or did you a copy and paste? you ahve to Show some effort i won't do the work for you. there is a call to asc in the RC4Initialize functino in the first loop

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I made it.
I just replaced each asc to ascW
and each chr to chrW and it works perfect.